#  Building multiprocessor motherboard

Tags: board, processor

I would like to build a multi processor motherboard using ARM processors (e.g. the ARM Cortex A8 or A9 or others as well), for low-power computing.
Is this possible ? I mean interconnecting the processors ... or the maximum I can do is putting e.g. 5 processors, RAM modules, EEPROM, etc (separated for each processor) and let one processor only coardinate the timing between them ?

I would do this only for the fun now, but I cant exlude the possibility of running this on an actual machine (server maybe). I want to install GNU/Linux over it (maybe Debian GNU/Linux).
Right now I'm a student in electronics and electrical engineering in bachelor 3rd year ... would like to do this in the summer holidays since we have a printed circuit board lab in our school which we can use almost for free.

Comment: There is no sensible limit to what you CAN do apart from your ingenuity. There are sensible limits to what you would want to do. Itprobably makes more sense to mke modules of a finite size that are interconnected by eg "ethernet" - depending in what "interconnect" means to you.

Comment: @Russel McMahon: this could be a nice idea, like the server board with 20 ARM processors they made. However I was thinking of a low-cost solution and I don't know how much more ethernet support will cost (socket, pcb space, copper, ...). And I wanted to avoid, if possible, to install the OS on all of the EEPROM / small SSD / ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inter-processor communication is possible and as you indicate some kind of bus arbiter would be needed for shared memory. I don't want to steal your joy, but what you are describing is a *huge* project. Unless your school lab is really advanced it is also likely that the PCB technology needed for this build (multi-layer, narrow isolation and maybe microvias) is missing.

If you want to experiment with parallel computing maybe a dual-core microcontroller (processors + peripherals in one package) would be a good start. You can find some LQFP packages that are easy to solder. An even better way could be to study an existing design such as the Pandaboard (http://pandaboard.org/).

Comment: +1 for describing the difficulties of this undertaking.  However, the Pandaboard has a dual-core processor, so the interconnect is largely invisible to the user.  Something like the [Gumstix Stagecoach](https://www.gumstix.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=247) would be better for this purpose.

Comment: If you want to get really extravagant, you can always stick a Sun Niagara SPARC core on a FPGA. 8 4-thread CPUs on a die (or, really, as many as you want). Probably not good for learning, but SPARCs are lovely CPUs.

Comment: @Alexios: did I mention I wanted to keep my budget under control :D ? Furthermore I don't see where I could buy such a cpu.

Comment: @Per E: I agree this would be a HUGE project. Well, since most of those in electrical engineering was constructing their microcontroller, IK though I could do something a bit more advanced, however I think you're right. At this point it would maybe be better to build N boards with a single / dual core microcontroller and connect them to a ethernet switch and let one of them manage the others. No shared RAM and other things should be simpler to do. I really wanted to try out the Raspberry PI before doing this but since it's unavailable ...

Comment: @Per E: somewhat I find the pandaboard a bit expensive (182$). A I don't understand if WLAN is integrated on the chip or it should be aded as a module (and there is the pin header connection for the module, which is sold separately).

Comment: @user51166: FPGAs aren't that expensive these days (and your project is huge and WILL get expensive — even the tools you'll need won't be cheap). Anyway, I bought an all-inclusive board with an FPGA on a PCI card, with Flash, RAM, sensors, clocks, etc for about £100. SPARC is an open architecture: free (as in freedom) hardware. You can download the core and synthesise it on an FPGA (some people have coded their own SPARC CPUs too). If you do the Niagara, the size of the FPGA determines how many CPU cores you can fit. Even with two, you have 16 threads of execution (but only one FPU).

Comment: @Alexios: any idea which shops I should look into (I'm in Switzerland, so for electronics Farnell and Digikey are normally the used shops but none of them has what you say). Do you have an example of product ID I can get more details on ? In fact maybe coding SPARC myself isn't a good idea (you're right about that). Thanks

Comment: @user51166: I'm afraid this if going a bit off-topic now... It is a separate chip (LS240-WI-01-A20) that is mounted in the north-east part of the board. I agree that it is a bit pricy, [this article](http://hackaday.com/2011/02/01/what-development-board-to-use/) contains a nice collection of different boards and prices. But then again it isn't related to your original question anymore.

Comment: @Per E: thanks for the article, very useful. I'll examine it in more details when I'll have more time. I just though these boards were overpriced but since their performance is more like an Atom (or more) than a microcontroller (like the Arduino's) it makes sense is not so cheap. If anybody has anything to add, please do, otherwise I think we can close. Definitevely not doing a multiprocessor board, maybe it can be fun to just do a microcontroller (if any) like Arduino's which seems more simple (than a multiprocessor board at least).